# How can we find deleted class in sandbox?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

I have one class in in my org. But now i couldn't see that class, I don't what happened. I have deployed to UAT and Productions. In UAT and Production also disappeared those class and process is not running. I've tried with below query

select id from apexclass where name ='deletedclass' . But i couldn't find.

Can anyone please help me to find that class?

Comment: I don't think that would be possible to get deleted class back. Best option is from your code backup(if you have) create them again.

Answer (score 6):

See this: [Is it possible to recover a deleted trigger or class?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181984&language=en_US)

> Currently, it is not possible to recover a deleted triggers or
>   classes.

However,

**you can retrieve the deleted class or trigger id from [workbench](http://workbench.developerforce.com) using
the following SOQL query:**

```
Select Id,Name from ApexTrigger where status='deleted' or
name='classname'
```

After getting the Id, you may try to browse to the following URL: **https://instancename.salesforce.com/trigger-or-class-id** to see if the code of the trigger/class is still accessible.

Comment: How about `undelete`? No dice?

Comment: @AdrianLarson i didn't get you this time :) Would you explain what you want to say a littile bit?

Comment: I was just wondering if you could call `undelete` on the deleted class, if you can still query for it.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Actually i sort of try this solution before posting, with workbench, both with tooling API and simple query but i always got zero results ;) but on some other threads i saw that people got the IDs so thought this might worth a try. Still not sure about` undelete` how do u want to call that but the doc says if you get the id then try if that class is still accessible,if yes then open and save it again.